# Can I put a select button on the header of this dashboard?

Tags: website-design, buttons, responsive-design, dashboard

I have a dashboard using [balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/), which having a list of doctors and I want to put them on the sider sorted alphabetically, and I want to display, for each doctor, different pages like Gestion de plannings/ Gestion d'activités et gestion de consignes.

It can be possible to put a select button, having the name of this page, on the header of this dashboard ?

[image]

Have you a suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my understanding you want a list of doctors and for each doctor you want them to have their own menu that includes selections such as Gestion de plannings/ Gestion d'activités and gestion de consignes.

If this is correct, I think you should have the selections close to the name of the doctor so that the user understands the two are associated with each other. The Law of Proximity states (quick google search), "elements that are close together tend to be perceived as a unified group. This straightforward law states that items close to each other tend to be grouped together, whereas items further apart are less likely to be grouped together." Otherwise, your user may not understand Gestion de plannings is for a specific doctor.

If you want the selections at the top, you can add the doctors name next to it like Dr. Bob Ross: [Gestion de plannings]. Or you could have the selections on the side under each doctor. Whatever way you choose, make sure it's clear that the pages are specific to a doctor.

[image: two versions of having selections next to a doctor's name]

Comment: Thank you, It means, for each doctor, we have a menuItem Gestion des plannings /des consignes, etc ? like this https://ibb.co/5xytqHr ? what is the best solution please ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I would only show the menu items for one doctor at a time if you go this way (your version), example: expand the menu when you click one a doctor's name and when you click on the next doctor, the previous menu collapses as the menu for the new doctor expands. Just so you don't end up with a huge expanded list. And you don't know what is the best solution until you test it with your users.

Comment: It is clear, thank you.